# Magento2 set image size in etc/view.xml

Tags: magento2, xml

I have this XML to set my image sizes for both related products and my catalog widget on my home page. The Related Products portion works but the home page one doesn't.

```
<media>
    <images module="Magento_Catalog">
        <image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
            <width>222</width>
            <height>222</height>
        </image>
        <image id="category_page_grid" type="small_image">
            <width>222</width>
            <height>222</height>
        </image>
    </images>
</media>
```

Comment: Can you please specify file path of view.xml.

Comment: My_Theme/etc/view.xml

Comment: Which size its displays on Home page?

Comment: I found my issue. I called the wrong image id.            <image id="new_products_content_widget_grid" type="small_image">
                <width>222</width>
                <height>222</height>
                <aspect_ratio>true</aspect_ratio>
            </image>